# Changing src attribute in video tag with json data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, html5-video

I'm trying to make a video player with HTML and JavaScript that will play a series of videos, one after another, until all 6 have been played. The URLs for the videos are stored in an array and map in a .json file called clips.json.

The data in the file is below:

```
    [
{
    "id":"ashklasd132asddfgdf",
    "name": "War on Drugs continues",
    "description":"Losses continue in agressive raid on local property",
    "content-url": "http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/Kitty.mp4",
    "thumb-url":"http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/thumb/dogs_friends-t2.jpg"
},
{
    "id":"asdasd132asddf667jf",
    "name": "Parlimentary Proceedings",
    "description":"World Leaders meet to determine the latest policies on climate change relief",
    "content-url": "http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/Clouds%2038%20Timelapse.mp4",
    "thumb-url":"http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/thumb/colorful_clouds-t2.jpg"
},
{
    "id":"123dfg6132asddfgdz",
    "name": "Weather for March 22nd 2015",
    "description":"Join Jeremy Brown for today's weather",
    "content-url": "http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/Clouds-Time_lapse_22.mp4",
    "thumb-url":"http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/thumb/hidden_lagoon-t2.jpg"
},
{
    "id":"pzxc87asdkjl44h7h",
    "name": "Taking a walk on the wide-side",
    "description":"Cook Counties latest conservation efforts led to a new discovery",
    "content-url": "http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/Flower_4.mp4",
    "thumb-url":"http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/thumb/nature_scenes_3-t2.jpg"
},
{
    "id":"mkiaasdsjdh7asd8889",
    "name": "Musical Stunner",
    "description":"Local musician proves nay-sayers wrong by providing ample range",
    "content-url": "http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/Piano_keys.mp4",
    "thumb-url":"http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/thumb/turkey_karadeniz_region-t2.jpg"
},
{
    "id":"zklsjdpoiqwehbhfyvfy6h",
    "name": "H-Diddy Represent",
    "description":"The newest Album from H-Diddy",
    "content-url": "http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/Pigeon.mp4",
    "thumb-url":"http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/thumb/nanxiang_ancient_town_shanghai_china-t2.jpg"
},
]
```

I'm having trouble changing the `src` attribute after the video from the URL is finished. After the video plays the first video, it stops, and doesn't go on to the 2nd one. I don't know if it's because I'm calling the JSON data wrong with my AJAX get request or something else, but if someone could help me solve this issue, I'd greatly appreciate it.

My HTML code with embedded JavaScript is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>IIT News</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.starter-template {
    padding: 40px 15px;
      text-align: center;
   }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myJS.js" language="javascript">   </script>

</head>

 <body onload="loadFunction()">
<div class="container">
  <div class="hook">
    <video  onended="playNext()" width="640" height="480" id="myVideo" controls autoplay>
        <!--<source src="parsedData[0].['content-url'][conUrlCount]" type="video/mp4"></source>-->
        <source src="http://buffalogrove.sat.iit.edu/Kitty.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
  </div><!-- /.hook -->
</div><!-- /.container-->


</body>
</html>
```

myJS.js is below

```
        var conUrlCount = 0;
        var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");

        //parsedData should be declared outside the function scope since we want it to be accessible from outside
        var parsedData;
        var callback = function (text) {
            //parsedData = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(text));
            parsedData = JSON.parse(text);
            conUrlCount = 0;
            //after load play the first video
            playNext();
        };

        //when page is loaded, data in json file is parsed and returned
        function loadFunction() {
            //returning json data
            ajax.get("clips.json", callback);
        };


        function playNext() {
            if (!parsedData) {
                return
            }
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
            myVideo.src = parsedData[conUrlCount]['content-url'];
            myVideo.play();
            conUrlCount++;
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the json object is a local variable to the callback method, make it a global one

```
<video  onended="playNext()" width="640" height="480" id="myVideo" controls
```

autoplay>

then

```
var conUrlCount = 0;
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");

//parsedData should be declared outside the function scope since we want it to be accessible from outside
var parsedData;
var callback = function (text) {
    parsedData = JSON.parse(text);
    conUrlCount = 0;
    //after load play the first video
    playNext();
};

//when page is loaded, data in json file is parsed and returned
function loadFunction() {
    //returning json data
    ajax.get("clips.json", callback);
};


function playNext() {
    if (!parsedData) {
        return
    }
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    myVideo.src = parsedData[conUrlCount]['content-url'];
    myVideo.play();
    conUrlCount++;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dkLzqgbd/)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sadly, with the code provided, I wasn't able to produced the videos one after another. I saw you `stringify` your json data. Should I do that too? I made edits to my original code to show what changes I've made. I also linked to a javascript page in the hopes that that would fix the problem.